# ScreenToClient function for visual c++ picturebox

Tags: visual-c++, picturebox

i want to get co-ordinates of of my mouse in the picturebox.
i used ScreenToClient but i am getting some problems.

```
                            HWND hwnd;
            hwnd = pictureBox1->Handle;
            ScreenToClient(hwnd,&point);
```

where point has the absolute co-ordinates of the mouse.
the error i get is "cannot convert from 'System::IntPtr' to 'HWND'" for second line of the code. how do i get the handle of a picture box?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
hwnd = (HWND)pictureBox1->Handle.ToPointer();
```

BTW, it is better to keep this code pure managed, use Control.PointToClient and Control.PointToScreen methods to convert between screen and client coordinates.

Comment: again an error
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'POINT' to 'System::Drawing::Point'

i used 
PointToClient(point);

Comment: The answer is edited. Regarding PointToClient - show exact code and error message.

Comment: POINT point;
GetCursorPos(&point);
PointToClient(point);
    
 x = point.x;
 y = point.y;
    label3-> Text=Convert::ToString(x);
label4-> Text=Convert::ToString(y);

Comment: error is
 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'POINT' to 'System::Drawing::Point'

Comment: point variable should have type System::Drawing::Point, and not POINT Windows API structure. Don't mix managed and unmanaged types is this is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: So, what should i write? :(, is getcursorpos() required? please help

Comment: label3-> Text=Convert::ToString(e->X);
label4-> Text=Convert::ToString(e->Y);

i used this to get co-ordinates with respect to the picture box, instead of getting it from GetCursorPos func and PointToClient func.